# Unable to receive mail with PHPMailer v6

Tags: php, phpmailer

When I use this code (attached below), I am unable to receive mail with attachment but receive the status of url success. When I remove unlink(), I also get the attachment uploaded in my server uploads folder. I think there is some problem with my PHPMailer code. Can anyone identify it?

I have PHPMailer, uploads, index.php, upload.php in my directory.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name <input type="text" name="name"></input><br /><br />
Email <input type="email" name="email"></input><br /><br />
Upload <input type="file" name="file" required><br /><br />
<button type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

//Main Includes
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $file['name'];
$fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $file['size'];
$fileError = $file['error'];
$fileType = $file['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

if (empty($name) || empty($email)) {
    header("Location: index.php?empty");
    exit();
} else {
    //Check if input characters are valid
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $name)) {
        header("Location: index.php?invalidname");
        exit();
    } else {
        //Check if email is valid
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location: index.php?emailerror");
      exit();
        } else {
            if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
                if ($fileError === 0) {
                    if ($fileSize < 10000000) {
                        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                        $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

                        $mail = new PHPMailer();
                        $mail->addAddress('camadhusudanmishra@gmail.com');
                $mail->setFrom($email);
                    //  $mail->Subject = $subject;
                        $mail->isHTML(true);
                        $mail->Body = $name;
                        $mail->addAttachment($fileDestination);
                        $mail->send();

                        unlink($fileDestination);
                        header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
                        exit();
            }
                else {
                        echo "Your file is too big!";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "There was an error uploading your file!".$fileError;
                }
            } else {
                echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The initial problem is here //Main Includes
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

Comment: Dont send the email right away check $mail = new PHPMailer(); print_r($mail); see if you have got the mailer.

Comment: @FaizKhan unable to get you...

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous things wrong here - though I'm not sure what exactly is causing your problem.

Read [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) on handling file uploads. One issue is that you're not checking the return value of `move_uploaded_file` before continuing.

PHPMailer provides [an example of how to handle form file uploads correctly](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

PHPMailer validates all addresses that it uses before sending, so you can rely on that instead of doing your own validation as well.

When you're trying to debug something, don't issue redirects - they just make it harder to see what's going on.

You're not checking whether `$_FILES` exists or has anything in it before using it.

```
$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
```

That is a very weird way to get the extension. PHP has built-in functions for dismantling file paths, extracting extensions. It's safer to use them than roll your own:

```
$fileActualExt = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

You're missing a `use` statement for the `Exception` class - but you've not enabled PHPMailer's exceptions anyway (by passing `true` to the constructor). This may explain why you're not checking the return value from `send()`, which you should be doing if you're not using exceptions.

You're using the submitted email address as the From address - that's forgery and will cause SPF failures, resulting in send failures, bounces or spam filtering. The PHPMailer example shows how to do that correctly.